# How to create a drop down list that not using pop up link

Tags: html

I have created a dropdownlist that is using pop up link, but I want to change it to open in a new tab function because some of the browser such as safari that will not notify user this is the pop up link that make user think this dropdownlist is not a function at all so I want to change it, any suggestion or changing my code? Thanks

```
<div class="classddown2">
<select name="class-schedule-dropdown2" id="class-schedule-dropdown2" style="width: 1100px; color: #000000;">
    <option style='color: #000000'selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Class Schedule</option>
    <option style='color: #000000'value="http://www.example.com">example 1</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'class-schedule-dropdown2' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open(  this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding '_blank' as parameter for the option method should open your link in a new Tab:

`window.open(  this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');`

So your code would be this:

```
<div class="classddown2">
<select name="class-schedule-dropdown2" id="class-schedule-dropdown2" style="width: 1100px; color: #000000;">
    <option style='color: #000000'selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Class Schedule</option>
    <option style='color: #000000'value="http://www.example.com">example 1</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'class-schedule-dropdown2' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open(  this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');
 };
</script>
</div>
```

Or add the script directly to your select tag:

`<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')" name="class-schedule-dropdown2" id="class-schedule-dropdown2" style="width: 1100px; color: #000000;">`